# RetrievalQA streaming issue with chainlit UI

Tags: python, nlp, langchain

I have been trying to stream the answer from llm to Chainlit UI. I am using langchain library and RetrievalQA chain to combine llm,prompt and vector store with memorybuffer. I tried streaming the LLMchain first on cli and then chainlit ui. It works perfectly. But when I am try to use the RetrievalQA chain then it only works with cli and not streaming the tokens to the chainlit ui.

This is my code:

```
`from llama_cpp import Llama
from langchain.chains import LLMChain,QAWithSourcesChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.llms import CTransformers
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
import chainlit as cl
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_aiter_final_only import AsyncFinalIteratorCallbackHandler
from langchain.callbacks.manager import AsyncCallbackManagerForRetrieverRun
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_aiter_final_only import AsyncFinalIteratorCallbackHandler

DB_FAISS_PATH = 'vectorstores/db_faiss'

custom_prompt_template="""
 Below is an instruction that describes a task. Write a response that appropriately completes the request from the given context.
    ### Chat History:
    {chat_history}
    ## Context:
    {context}
    ### Instruction:
    {question}
    ### Response:
    """
def set_custom_prompt():
    """
    Prompt template for QA retrieval for each vectorstore
    """
    prompt = PromptTemplate(template=custom_prompt_template,
                            input_variables=["chat_history","context","question"])
    return prompt
custom_prompt_llmchain="""
 Below is an instruction that describes a task. Write a response that appropriately completes the request from the given context.
    ### Instruction:
    {question}
    ### Response:
    """


def set_custom_prompt_1():
    """
    Prompt template for QA retrieval for each vectorstore
    """
    prompt = PromptTemplate(template=custom_prompt_llmchain,
                            input_variables=["question"])
    return prompt
#Loading the model
def load_llm():
    llm = CTransformers(
    model="H:\WPCS_OPS_MERGED\OPS_WPCS_Q4.gguf", 
    model_type="llama",
    callbacks=[AsyncFinalIteratorCallbackHandler()],
    config={
    "temperature":0.15,
    # "max_new_tokens":512,
    # verbose=True,
    # streaming=True,
    "context_length":1800,
    "top_k":30,
    "repetition_penalty":1.2}
)
    return llm
def create_chain():
    llm_chain = LLMChain(
            llm=load_llm(),
            prompt=set_custom_prompt_1(),
            verbose=True,
        )
    return llm_chain
def create_chain_qa():
    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2",
                                       model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})
    db = FAISS.load_local(DB_FAISS_PATH, embeddings)
    qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=load_llm(),
                                       chain_type='stuff',
                                       retriever=db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 3}),
                                       verbose=True,
                                       return_source_documents=False,
                                       chain_type_kwargs={'prompt': set_custom_prompt(),"verbose":True,"memory":ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history",input_key="question",max_token_limit=150,return_messages=True)}
                                       )
    return qa_chain
# if __name__=="__main__":
#     chain=create_chain()
#     a=chain.run("How can I access the Service Status Page for HLA?")
@cl.on_chat_start
async def start():
    chain = create_chain_qa()
    msg = cl.Message(content="Starting the bot...")
    await msg.send()
    msg.content = "Hi, Welcome to AHS Bot. What is your query?"
    await msg.update()
    cl.user_session.set("chain", chain)
from langchain.callbacks.base import BaseCallbackHandler

class StreamHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = cl.Message(content="")

    async def on_llm_new_token(self, token: str, **kwargs):
        await self.msg.stream_token(token)

    async def on_llm_end(self, response: str, **kwargs):
        await self.msg.send()
        self.msg = cl.Message(content="")
@cl.on_message
async def main(message):
    chain = cl.user_session.get("chain") 
    cb = cl.AsyncLangchainCallbackHandler(
        stream_final_answer=True,
        answer_prefix_tokens=["FINAL", "ANSWER"]
    )
    # print(cb)
    # msg=cl.Message("")
    cb.answer_reached = True
    res = await chain.acall(message, callbacks=[cb])




    # # answer = res["result"]
    # async for part in res:
    #     if token := part.choices[0].text or "":
    #         await msg.stream_token(token)
    # await cl.Message(res["text"]).send()`
```

It would be great if anyone could give me a hand or provide a solution to solve this problem.